Differentiability of the function composition
I found an exercise problem for Korean SAT:

Let $f(x)$ be a quartic function $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+c$ $(a,b,c \in \mathbb{R})$ with $f(1)=0$ and $g(x)=2xe^x$. 
When
$$ h(x) = f(|g(x)|)+|g(f(x))|$$
is differentiable at any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, find  $\min\{f(-3)\}+\max\{f(-3)\}$.

Unfortunately, I only could know the answer $256$ without any solution.
Here is my approach:

Since $h(x)=\begin{cases} f(g(x))-g(f(x)) & (x<1) \\ & \\ f(g(x))+g(f(x)) & (x \geq 1) \end{cases}$, we have $g'(f(1))f'(1)=g'(0)f'(1)=2f'(1)=0$. 
So $f(x)=(x-1)^2 \left(x^2 + \alpha x + \beta \right)$.
If there exists $t \neq 0$ such that $f(t)=0$ and $f'(t) \neq 0$,
$h(x)=\begin{cases} f(\pm g(x))-g(f(x)) & (x<t) \\ & \\ f(\pm g(x))+g(f(x)) & (x \geq t) \end{cases}$ or $h(x)=\begin{cases} f(\pm g(x))+g(f(x)) & (x<t) \\ & \\ f(\pm g(x))-g(f(x)) & (x \geq t) \end{cases}$.
Then $g'(f(t))f'(t)=g'(0)f'(t)=2f'(t)=0$. Contradiction.
Thus, $f'(t)=0$ when $f(t)=0$, and then $f(x) \geq 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Note that $h(x)=\begin{cases} f(g(x))+g(f(x)) & (x<0) \\ & \\ f(-g(x))+g(f(x)) & (x \geq 0) \end{cases}$.
Therefore, $f'(g(0))g'(0)=2f'(0)=0$. 
Then $f'(0)=-2\beta + \alpha = 0$ and $f(x)=(x-1)^2 \left( x^2 + 2\beta x + \beta \right)$.
Since $f(x) \geq 0$, by the discriminant, $\beta^2 - \beta \leq 0 \Rightarrow 0 \leq \beta \leq 1$.
Now $64 \leq f(-3)=16(9-5\beta) \leq 144 \Rightarrow \min\{f(-3)\}+\max\{f(-3)\} = 208$.

Is there any mistakes in my approach?

$f(-3)$  is a number (that you can give in terms of $a,b,c,d$). It does not make sense to ask about its minimum or maximum.

@Medo As I mentioned in my approach, we can actually find the range of $f(-3)$ with the given condition.

You need to minimize $(a,b,c)\mapsto 81-27 a+9b +c$ over the set ${(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: f\circ |\cdot|\circ g, |\cdot|\circ g \circ f;\text{are differentiable}}$.

Well. $f$ and $g$ are smooth. So the question is what are the zeros of $g$ and $g\circ f$. First $g=0$ only at $x=0$. And $g\circ f$ vanishes only at the zeros of $f$.

With a slightly differnt approach, I found the same result $208$. Are you sure of your version of the question? And are you sure the answer should be $256$?

@AnneBauval Now I am doubting that case - the answer might be a typo. Unfortunately, I cannot check it since the source is quite old and the solution is missing. As I tried several more approaches and they gave the same answer 208, I am more and more believing that this is a typo.

I can't follow your approach, but mine leads to the same conclusions:
First note that for $n=0,2,3,4$, $|g|^n$ is differentiable everywhere, so $f\circ|g|$ is a decoy. The hypothesis of differentiability of $h=f\circ|g|+|g|\circ f$ is equivalent to that of $|g|\circ f$, i.e. of $|f|$, which means: every real root of $f$ is a multiple root, i.e. (since $f(1)=0$):
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2(x^2+\alpha x+\beta),\quad\alpha^2-4\beta\le0.$$ The additional assumption that $f(x)$ has no monomial of degree $1$ is then equivalent to $\alpha=2\beta$, so
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2(x^2+2\beta x+\beta),\quad\beta^2-\beta\le0$$
hence
$$f(-3)=16(9-5\beta),\quad0\le\beta\le1$$
and
$$\min\{f(-3)\}+\max\{f(-3)\}=16\left((9-5\cdot1)+(9-5\cdot0)\right)=16\cdot13=208.$$
